# Buyers in Eve Regional Market

Tags: eve-online

Sometimes I am able to see buyers in the Eve regional market from many jumps away. Othertimes, it seems that I have to be in the system to actually see all of the buyers in that system.

I would have thought that all buyers for an item in your current region would be shown. But, it doesn't seem like it works that way, having some sort of jump limit.

What effects how far I can see buyers?

Comment: I think that, though it's been a while since I played so won't post as an answer, there's a couple of skills in the trade group that affect how visible your buy and sell orders are. There's also a filter on the trade screen to show only local orders, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have filters configured in the "Settings" tab "Filtering Options" of the Regional Market window you should see all buy and sell orders for an item in your current region.

Things that don't affect buy order visibility but sound like they should:-

1. The Regional Market window "Range Filter" drop down and "Show Only
   Available" checkbox only affect the product tree and not the buy and
   sell order lists.
2. The buyer can control how far from their current station their order
   can be fulfilled when it's created (Station, Solar System, # Jumps,
   Region) but not it's region-wide visibility.
3. The [Visibility skill](https://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Visibility) affects how far from their selected remote
   station a buyer can have their order fulfilled using the
   [Procurement skill](https://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Procurement), but again doesn't affect visibility. Despite
   the skill name.